# How to reload children controller?

Tags: ember.js

I have a page with few sections. I use controller, template and view for each section. Also I have parent controller, route, template and view.

Every thing works well. But I'd like to reload children containers when my parent container get new value.

For example, in one section user clicks a button and I should update every section.

How can I do it?

I know how to call parent from children:

```
needs: "post"
```

Comment: What version of Ember are you working with here?  Views and Controllers have generally been replaced by components.

Comment: maybe you could use Observers? https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.6.0/object-model/observers/